# AWS Region change for AWS resources

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created an ETL pipeline in us-east-1 region, but I need it to migrate it as whole with data catalog to a different region. is that possible? I know I can CRR S3, create the lambda functions and Glue jobs there, but the database, how can I make a copy of it there?

I just need ways to replicate the Database other things can be done one way or another. The Lake formation database and table that are stored in it.

Thanks

Comment: There is no facility to 'migrate' AWS services between regions. The standard practice would be to deploy infrastructure via CloudFormation so that it can then be deployed exactly the same in a different region. What is the 'Database' you mention -- is it Amazon RDS, or are you referring to the AWS Glue Data Catalog which simply contains DDL that points to data in Amazon S3?

Comment: Got it, so glue data catalog does not hold data. Thanks